# Currency format react

Tags: reactjs

I wanna change the format of this input to currency format

```html
   <TextInput name="Amount" type="Text"
              floatingLabelText={messages.AMOUNT[lang]}
              errorText={err.Amount}
              value={} onChange={this.handleChange} required 
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a method like the following:

```js
const priceSplitter = (number) => (number && number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ','));

console.log(priceSplitter(72500));
```